# React native expo web build is giving error. After upgrading expo 49 to 50

Tags: react-native, expo

This is the error response I'm getting.

[image]

App build works fine but web build doesn't. This happened right after I updated expo and it's dependencies to 50.

The file ../../Utilities/Platform exists

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue. Will let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: Thank you, I found a solution. Please check if yours is same.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the import of Colors.

```
import { Colors } from "react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen";
```

Which was causing the issue, funny part was I wasn't even using it. After deleting the line

```
> npx expo export -p web
```

Worked like a charm!